# Refresh de uma <input> contendo valores do Banco de Dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Olá vamos começar a explicar oque eu preciso kkk

Basicamente é um jogo onde eu Ataco, após atacar ele insere na DB os turnos de CD, e a cada novo ataque reduz o tempo em 1, oque eu queria fazer era ele pegar o valor do banco e se o valor existir ou seja for >0 ele coloca o Ataque em Cooldown, até ai funciona bem com esse código

```php
<?php
    while($tecnica=mysql_fetch_assoc($tabela_tecnica_o)){   
    $tecnica_cd = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `batalha_npc_tecnicas` WHERE `jogador`='".$_SESSION['personagem']."' AND `tecnica_id`='".$tecnica['tecnica_id']."'");
    $tecnica_cd = $db->fetch($tecnica_cd);
    // Aqui ele busca a CD no Banco de Dados e Retorna
    ?>
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function () {
        if('<?=$tecnica_cd['cd']?>'>0){
        $("#tec-<?=$tecnica['id']?>").css('opacity',0.5);
        }
    }, 1000);
        </script>
```

Porem eu notei que mesmo ele dando "refresh" no Ataque para atualizar a CD ele não atualiza o valor buscado na DB, apenas quando eu dou F5 na pagina... alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?
A Input para caso de duvidas

```
<input type="submit" style="font-size:20px;color:#fff;border:0px;background:url(images/tecnicas/<?=$tecnica['tecnica_id']?>.png);float:left;margin-right:7px;height:90px;cursor:pointer;width:110px;background-size:110px 90px;" id="tec-<?=$tecnica['id']?>" value="" class="teste4" title="<?=$texto?>" data="<?=$tecnica['id']?>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia amigo

O seu problema é que a sua condicional para disparar a ação que você quer, só acontece quando você atualiza a pagina, isso provavelmente deve acontecer pois você não tem um trigger (gatilho) que dispare o evento.

Vou te dar outro exemplo que vai conseguir te fazer pensar. Digamos que tenhamos um código PHP na pagina, como você deve saber o PHP ele é interpretado pelo servidor, então a maioria dos triggers dele vai ser relacionado a eventos do servidor. Já o JS ele é "interpretado" pelo navegador, então eventos no navegador iram disparar a maioria dos eventos dele.

Resumindo, seu código está bem ruim de ler. Mas eu te aconselho a mover toda essa logica para a parte de JS, você pode supervisionar esse botão de ataque, e quando ele for disparado você faz um requisição para algum endpoint para seu servidor php.

Comment: Estou mexendo diretamente no .js para fazer isso imagino que seja como você disse


```
     if(datas.t_cd) $("#tec-"+datas.t_cd).attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('opacity',0.5).val(datas.t_turnos_cd);
     
     if(datas.t_desblock_o) $("#tec-"+datas.t_desblock_o).removeAttr('disabled').css('opacity',1).val(""); 
    
```
Porem ele só faz 1 por vez quando o botão é clicado e não ambas